# How to add a static secondary IP to a DHCP interface using netplan?

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, static-ip, netplan

My server has a file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml with the following content:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:**:**:**:**:**
            set-name: ens3
```

This results in the following interface configuration:

```
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       ...
```

So far, so good.  But now I need to add 10.0.0.250 as an additional secondary static IP to this interface.  What is the best way to do that?  I created a new file /etc/netplan/60-service-ip.yaml with:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            addresses:
              - 10.0.0.5/24
              - 10.0.0.250/24
```

This seems to work, but it re-defines a dynamic IP as a static one.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually way easier, you just add `dhcp4: true` to your static configuration like this (and disable v6 if you don't need it):

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: yes
            dhcp6: no
            addresses:
              - 10.0.0.250/24
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a same issue where I have dhcp address as secondary and static as primary in Azure.
Leaving dhcp address as primary is important because Azure virtual network provides gateway and nameserver information.

I found this workaround:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
          dhcp4: true
          addresses:
              - 10.0.2.6/24 (IP acquired by DHCP)
              - 10.0.2.21/24
          match:
              macaddress: 00:0d:3a:4f:45:f0
          set-name: eth0
```

In Azure specifically, we assign static ip address on Azure Resource side and normally this is taken to Guest OS by dhcp.
Therefore, even though guest os treats it as a dynamic ip, it will always get same static ip from Azure.
Above, I forced to put dhcp IP ahead of secondary IP.
In my case, it worked as expected.

Comment: But that defies using DHCP in the first place if you know which IP address that connection is going to be, doesn't it?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke Pick your poison, I guess. This should work for servers that only ever stay in the same network(s).

Answer (score 3):

[Answered on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031278/does-netplan-support-dhcp-and-static-addresses-on-one-interface)

Copy:

The solution was quite simple, just set a static IP address and enable DHCP. Basically you just have to add `dhcp4: yes` to your configuration.

This configuration gave me a primary static IP address and a secondary DHCP assigned IP address:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: 
        - 10.1.2.15/24
      gateway4: 10.1.2.1
      nameservers:
        search:
          - example.com
        addresses: [10.1.2.10]
```

The result of ip address show enp0s3 gave me:

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ab:cd:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.2.15/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.1.2.96/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 3224sec preferred_lft 3224sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe20:2c40/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The address 10.1.2.96 is the secondary DHCP assigned address as indicated by the secondary dynamic keywords.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the DHCP address being the secondary address.  However, it needs to be primary in order to make outgoing connections work.

Comment: Why does it have to be primary? Are you sure you don't just need source routing? or a different gateway per IP?

Comment: If the DHCP-based address is primary, everything works fine.  If it is secondary, outgoing connections hang.  See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1766656, especially comment #2.

Comment: Outgoing connections don't "hang", they may choose the wrong IP. I presume you got connections to some server/service/whatever which only work with the correct source IP?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and easier to automate) is just creating a second file named "/etc/netplan/60-static.yaml" with the content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.250/24
```

and execute:

```
netplan try
```

Comment: Thanks to https://gist.github.com/ThomasLeister/640812441505447ba8f19f85314fbf5b